# Write newline value to python file without it making a new line

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, escaping

I have a bit of an odd question but I'm trying to fix an issue I've been having. I have a python script that writes another stored python script to a new file. Problem is the script that it writes contains newline values (\n.) Instead of writing \n, it puts it in a new line. Any way around this?

```
f = open('email.py','r+')
readcontent = f.read()
f.seek(0, 0)
f.write('''\
def sendemail(from_addr, to_addr_list, cc_addr_list, subject, message, login, password, smtpserver='smtp.gmail.com:587'):
    header  = 'From: %s\n' % from_addr
    header += 'To: %s\n' % ','.join(to_addr_list)
    header += 'Cc: %s\n' % ','.join(cc_addr_list)
    header += 'Subject: %s\n' % subject
    message = header + message

    server = smtplib.SMTP(smtpserver)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(login,password)
    problems = server.sendmail(from_addr, to_addr_list, message)
    server.quit()
''')    
f.close()
```

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
f = open('email.py','r+',newline=None)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: replace`\n` with `\\n`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want Python to process backslash escapes in a string literal, prefix it with `r`:

```
f.write(r'''
...
''')
```

Comment: This fixed it + other issues in my code! Thank you so much. I'll accept this as the answer when I can.

Comment: @EvanEdwards You can always accept an answer (to my knowledge). Why can't you?

Comment: @EthanK there is a certain amount of time you need to wait before you can (~10 mins.)

Comment: Oh. I didn't know that. Thanks @EvanEdwards!

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping your backslashes. Right now your backslashes escape the "n" characters so that it's interpreted as a newline. You want to escape that whole thing again so what you get is for instance:

```
    header  = 'From: %s\\n' % from_addr
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to `replace`  `\n` to `\\n`

```
f = open('email.py','r+')
readcontent = f.read()
f.seek(0, 0)
f.write('''\
def sendemail(from_addr, to_addr_list, cc_addr_list, subject, message, login, password, smtpserver='smtp.gmail.com:587'):
    header  = 'From: %s\n' % from_addr
    header += 'To: %s\n' % ','.join(to_addr_list)
    header += 'Cc: %s\n' % ','.join(cc_addr_list)
    header += 'Subject: %s\n' % subject
    message = header + message

    server = smtplib.SMTP(smtpserver)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(login,password)
    problems = server.sendmail(from_addr, to_addr_list, message)
    server.quit()
'''.replace('\n', '\\n'))    
f.close()
```

Comment: That's going to replace the newlines that are supposed to be newlines, too.